# Dynamic redirection uri for InMemory client Spring Authorization Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-authorization-server

I am using Spring Authorization Server 1.1.2 for OAuth2 implementation with Spring Boot 3. For fetching oauth2 token, I have a custom page `OauthRedirect.html` which calls `oauth2/authorize` and `oauth2/token` endpoints and the token is displayed on the same page similar to Google Playground. My application will be hosted on a VM with docker where the host name will be dynamic.

Now, I have an InMemoryClient registered as below:

```
@Bean
  public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() throws UnknownHostException, ReflectionException, MalformedObjectNameException, AttributeNotFoundException, InstanceNotFoundException, MBeanException {
    RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        .clientId(oauthProperties.clientId)
        .clientSecret(passwordEncoder().encode(oauthProperties.clientSecret))
        .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
        .redirectUri("http://localhost:"+oauthProperties.localServerPort+"/oauthredirect) 
        .scope("read")
        .scope("write")
        .build();
    return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
  }
```

And below is the `oauth/authorize` call from UI as I want to come back to same page:

```
function authorizeApis() {
      let redirectUri = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
      window.location.href = 'oauth2/authorize?client_id=ecat&scope=read&response_type=code&response_mode=query&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri;
    }
```

This works fine for localhost. However,the issue is with `redirectUri` value when deployed on docker. It will change as per the hostname and port. How would my registered client will know the host and port at the time of bean creation to have the same `redirectUri` that UI is sending? I have tried using `InetAddress` to get the address but it does not work as expected. Also, I could not find something like `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` in authorization server. What can be the alternative for this? Please help.